# POST with attachment and general fields C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm Using C#.

I have few questions:

1. I want to know what is the "best" way to make HTTP request with attachments

   I can send a dictionary: { {"FileName": "a.txt", FileBase64Stream: "SOME BASE 64 STRING"}, {"FileName": "b.txt", FileBase64Stream: "SOME BASE 64 STRING"}}

   Or there is another way to send attachments?
2. I want to send general object (int,string, etc) as json, I did it in the following way:

   { {"value": "1.2", "type": "float"},  {"value": "1", "type": "int"}, {"value": "Hello", "type": "string"}, {"value": "00011111010101", "type": "bytes"}}

But in this case the client need to convert the value according the type, There is another way to send "general" object as JSON and to parse it?

Thakns

Comment: Use HTML5 File API (option 1).

Answer (score 0):

While Base64 encoding could be fine for small payloads, for larger files it will add too much overhead. I would recommend you using [`multipart/form-data`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#multipart/form-data-encoding-algorithm) as defined in [`RFC 2388`](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) instead as it allows you to directly send the files as binary streams. Most server side API frameworks have native support for `multipart/form-data` encoded requests. Here's an example payload:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

contents of a.txt come here
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="b.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

contents of b.txt come here
--AaB03x--
```

Regarding your second question about deserializing generic objects, the [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) package allows you to write a custom JsonConverter to handle this situation. You can start by modelling your data:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

and then writing a converter to handle it:

```
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyModel);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var json = JObject.Load(reader);
        JToken typeToken;
        JToken valueToken;
        if (json.TryGetValue("type", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, out typeToken) &&
            json.TryGetValue("value", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, out valueToken))
        {
            string type = typeToken.Value<string>().ToLowerInvariant();
            var model = new MyModel();
            model.Type = type;
            switch (type)
            {
                case "float":
                    model.Value = valueToken.Value<float>();
                    break;
                case "int":
                    model.Value = valueToken.Value<int>();
                    break;
                case "string":
                    model.Value = valueToken.Value<string>();
                    break;
                case "bytes":
                    string input = valueToken.Value<string>();
                    int count = input.Length / 8;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    {
                        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(8 * i, 8), 2);
                    }
                    model.Value = bytes;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("The specified type is not supported: " + type);
            }

            return model;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is use this converter when deserializing:

```
string json =
@"[{
    ""value"": 1.2,
    ""type"": ""float""
  }, {
    ""value"": 1,
    ""type"": ""int""
  }, {
    ""value"": ""Hello"",
    ""type"": ""string""
  }, {
    ""value"": ""00011111010101"",
    ""type"": ""bytes""
  }]";
var myConverter = new MyConverter();
var models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MyModel>>(json, myConverter);
```